# Followed a-z as per the official tutorial to install zabbix but getting error?

Tags: centos7, zabbix

This is the error that I'm getting.
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=centos&os_version=7&components=server_frontend_agent&db=mysql&ws=apache

I'm following this documentation for centos 7, zabbix version 5.0 LTS as you can see in the link above.
But I'm getting the above mentioned error when setting up database.
I've entered correct password, I'm sure of that.

I'm expecting it to accept the password.